# Player gets stuck on wall | Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a infinite runner game for android using Unity. The player runs (automatically) and has to avoid the obstacles by touching the screen and changing the gravity. But i sometimes when he hits the corner/side of the platform, the player gets stuck. I already applied a "noFriction" material on the player but it still happens sometimes.
(The small boxcollider under the player just checks if the player is touching the ground)

Here some pictures:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could add a Physics Material, that has it's Friction and Bounciness set to 0. Resulting in making you *slide* of platforms if you just hit them from the side.

[image: Physics Material]

You should also make sure to set RigidBody2D Collison Detection to Continuous.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, but as mentioned i already did that. It does slide of when touching the side of thr platform but sometimes when he rans/jumps against the side he still gets stuck. I think it happens when the corners of both box colliders collide, but not sure.

Comment: Edited my answer, please change the Collision Detection of your RigidBody to Continous and see if that helps.

Comment: i did but same problem

Comment: make sure to add the no friction material to the box colider. it will override the material in rigidbody.